# Why does for loop not work with array.size()?

Tags: java, android-studio, arraylist

This is my first time here and I am quite new to coding on Android Studio. I am trying to fill up an `ArrayList` using for loop but my coding on the for loop has some issues. I am also not sure what information I have to show. I think the problem might be adding variables to the array in the loop. Some of my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < foodis.size() ; i++) {

                if(beverage.get(i).getCalorie()>=(inputcalorie-100)&&beverage.get(i).getCalorie()<=(inputcalorie+100)){


                    foodtest=beverage.get(i).getFood();
                    calorietest=beverage.get(i).getCalorie();
                    Log.d("MyActivity","foodtest=" + foodtest);
                    Log.d("MyActivity","calorietest=" + calorietest);

                        foodis.add(new foodis(foodtest,calorietest));

                        Log.d("MyActivity","food=" + foodis.get(i).getFooddisplay());
                        Log.d("MyActivity","cal=" + foodis.get(i).getCaldisplay());


            }
```

Edit: I made an  `beverage`arraylist with data from a csv file (shown below)

```
Coffee,0
Coffee With Milk,150
Milo,371
Milo 50% Less Sugar,140
Apple Juice,46
Orange Juice ,45
Milk,149
Low Fat Milk,110
```

Class foodis:

```
public class foodis {

    public String fooddisplay;
    public Double caldisplay;

    public foodis(String fooddisplay, Double caldisplay) {
        this.fooddisplay = fooddisplay;
        this.caldisplay = caldisplay;
    }

    public String getFooddisplay() {
        return fooddisplay;
    }

    public void setFooddisplay(String fooddisplay) {
        this.fooddisplay = fooddisplay;
    }

    public Double getCaldisplay() {
        return caldisplay;
    }

    public void setCaldisplay(Double caldisplay) {
        this.caldisplay = caldisplay;
    }

}
```

Class beverage:

```
public class beverage {
    private String food;
    private Double calorie;


    public String getFood() {

        return food;
    }

    public void setFood(String food) {

        this.food = food;
    }

    public Double getCalorie() {

        return calorie;
    }

    public void setCalorie(Double calorie)
    {
        this.calorie = calorie;
    }




    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FoodSample{" +
                ", food='" + food + '\'' +
                ", calorie=" + calorie +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to clarify that when  I changed the upper limit of the loop to ```foodis.size()``` the loop doesnt work at all. I thought that ```foodis.size()``` initial value will be 0 .

Comment: What are the arrays `foodis` and `beverage` ? How are they initialized ?

Comment: The _meaning_ here is unclear. It would probably be a lot simpler to say `for (Beverage b: beverages)` instead of trying to somehow mix the _contents_ of `beverages` and the _count_ of `foodis`.

Comment: I edited the post and added some code related to the arrays. Currently, I am trying to add data from ```beverages``` into ```foodis``` through the for loop but for loop doesnt work.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays in Java start from 0 (Zero), so `foodis.size()` will return 4 if there are 4 entries in the list but the index ends at 3 as it starts from 0.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
```

Comment: "so `foodis.size()` will return 3 if there are 4 entries in the list." – if there are 4 entries in the list then the _size_ is 4 and the `size` method will report as such; the last _index_, however, will be 3.

Comment: You got the point, I will re-phrase it in the answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But the for loop doesn't work when i use ```foodis.size()``` , the ```java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3 ``` only happens when I change ```foodis.size()``` to an Integer. To clarify, Arrays in Java start from 0 but does it work the same way for Arraylist? Because the for loop should work if the ArrayList size starts from 0.

Comment: I guess you edited the initial question/code, as now I see that you are adding to the same array you are looping trough..

Comment: @deftVG An `ArrayList` is zero based; this is a property of all `List` implementations, not just `ArrayList`. As for your code, you seem to be iterating over the indices of `foodis` yet you're accessing `beverage` with those indices, thus you're assuming `beverage` has the same size as `foodis`.